# Is it possible that numba jit slows down my gcd execution?

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm trying to compute a large amount of `GCD(x,y)` as part of [Euler 625](https://projecteuler.net/problem=625) and since this takes a lot of time, I tried adding `@numba jit` to speed it up.

I checked similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988579/numba-slows-down-my-program-instead-of-speeding-it-up), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226006/jit-slowing-down-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155781/numba-jit-slower-that-pure-python) but they are not helpful (I'm not using `numpy` or using a parallel-able functions (like `sum`) and I called the functions several times - so compiling laziness isn't the issue either)
The results are :

```
with    numba: 8.220806121826172 seconds
without numba: 1.242861270904541 seconds
```

my code is added below.

1. why is numba slowing me down?
2. how can I execute this faster (the original limit is 10**11, which is incomputable in this way as it seems)

   ```
   import time
   from numba import jit, int32

   gcd_dict = {}

   #@jit
   def gcd(x, y ,k = None, reverse_k = None):

       if not k:
           k = (x,y)
           reverse_k = (y,x)

       if k in gcd_dict:
           return gcd_dict[k]
       elif reverse_k in gcd_dict:
           return gcd_dict[reverse_k]

       if not y:
           if len(gcd_dict) < 10**6:
               gcd_dict[k] = x
               gcd_dict[reverse_k] = x
           return x
       else:
           return gcd(y, x % y, k, reverse_k)



   def main():
       t = time.time()
       s = 0
   #    i_limit = 10**11+1
       i_limit = 10**3

       for i in range(1,i_limit):
           for j in range(1,i+1):
               s += gcd(i,j)

       print(s)
       print(time.time() - t)

   main()
   ```

Comment: I don't get how you arrive at the conclusion that numba slowed you down: you show that numba provided you with a 7x speedup (from 8.2 to 1.2 seconds).

Comment: Silly mistake. I swapped the lines :-( ... The jitted version is the slower, as the title states

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are not supported by `numba`, thus it falls back to Python mode which causes runtime overhead.

You can see that JIT compilation fails if you replace `@jit`  by `@jit(nopython=True)` which disables switching to Python so that you get an error message in case you use unsupported Python features.